# How to break the while loop if data is not receiving and data length is unknow in python [TCP]

Tags: python, sockets, while-loop, tcpclient

I am new in python and socket programming. I am trying to send data to the client, and the length of data is unknown. After receiving all the data on client side, the program is not terminating because of a while loop (See below code). I also use the command (if not message: break) but it is also not working.
The second one is the packet loss issue. When I do not give time. Sleep () at the sender side then receiver miss some packet(does not receive all packets at receiver side where the sender sends all packets).
How I can come out from while loop without sys.exit command?.
and ....How I can handle the second issue without using time.sleep function.
It is appreciable if anybody can help me.
Thanks

[Receiver Node]

```
import socket
import os,sys


def frame_reception_function ():
    while True:
        PORT = 123
        s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)
        s.bind(('',PORT))
        s.listen()
        conn,address=s.accept()
        message=conn.recv(4096).decode()
        print (message)
        conn.close()
frame_reception_function()
```

[Sender node]

```
import os,sys
import socket
import time


MyNeighborSet_ip= ['192.168.1.2']


Data_transfer_listt = [['192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.2'], ['192.168.1.2', '192.168.1.3'], ['192.168.1.2', '192.168.1.4'], ['192.168.1.4', '192.168.1.5'], ['192.168.1.4', '192.168.1.6']]



def sending_Neighobr_ip_list():    
    #nn1=n1
    message='Neighbor_list_sending'
    #print (len(Data_transfer_listt))

    for i in range(len(Data_transfer_listt)):
        receiver_ip=Data_transfer_listt[i][0]
        receiver_node_list=Data_transfer_listt[i][1]
        T_message= message + ";" + receiver_ip + ";" + receiver_node_list
        T_message_bytes= bytes(T_message,'utf-8')
        PORT = 123
        print ("just after socket")
        for k in range (len(MyNeighborSet_ip)):
            s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)
            s.connect((MyNeighborSet_ip[k],PORT))
            s.sendall (T_message_bytes) 
            s.close()
            time.sleep(0.01)


sending_Neighobr_ip_list()
```

Comment: you mentioned using a 'break' for your while loop. where is it?

Comment: @  bunbun yes i use break after this message=conn.recv(4096).decode() line at receiver side but it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very resource intensive to keep opening and closing a socket, I am going to take those out of the while loop. Also, I can't remember if `recv` is a blocking function or not. But this should help you break out of the while loop properly and solve your first problem.

Receiver:

```
def frame_reception_function ():
    data = []
    PORT = 123
    s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)
    s.bind(('0.0.0.0',PORT))
    s.listen(1)
    conn,address=s.accept()  # accept an incoming connection using accept() method which will block until a new client connects
    while True:
        datachunk=conn.recv(1024) # reads data chunk from the socket in batches of 4086 bytes using method recv() until it returns an empty string
        if not datachunk:
            break  # no more data coming in, so break out of the while loop
        data.append(datachunk)  # add chunk to your already collected data

    conn.close()
    print(data)
    return

frame_reception_function()
```

Sender:

```
import os,sys
import socket
import time

MyNeighborSet_ip= [<THE IP ADDRESS OF YOUR RECEIVER>]

Data_transfer_listt = [['192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.2'], ['192.168.1.2', '192.168.1.3'], ['192.168.1.2', '192.168.1.4'], ['192.168.1.4', '192.168.1.5'], ['192.168.1.4', '192.168.1.6']]

def sending_Neighobr_ip_list():
    #nn1=n1
    message='Neighbor_list_sending'
    #print (len(Data_transfer_listt))
    PORT = 123

    for k in range (len(MyNeighborSet_ip)): 
        s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect((MyNeighborSet_ip[k],PORT))
        s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)

        for i in range(len(Data_transfer_listt)):
            receiver_ip=Data_transfer_listt[i][0]
            receiver_node_list=Data_transfer_listt[i][1]
            T_message= message + ";" + receiver_ip + ";" + receiver_node_list
            T_message_bytes= bytes(T_message)

            print("sending message")
            s.sendall (T_message_bytes)

        s.close()

sending_Neighobr_ip_list()
```

For `THE IP ADDRESS OF YOUR RECEIVER`, I used my local IP address (192.168.x.x).

This is the output on the receiver side:

```
['Neighbor_list_sending;192.168.1.1;192.168.1.2', 'Neighbor_list_sending;192.168.1.2;192.168.1.3', 'Neighbor_list_sending;192.168.1.2;192.168.1.4', 'Neighbor_list_sending;192.168.1.4;192.168.1.5', 'Neighbor_list_sending;192.168.1.4;192.168.1.6']
```

The problem is on the sender side, you are closing the socket every iteration. That makes the receiver close its connection too. So sender successfully sends the first message, then errors out on the second connection cause receiver has been closed and is not looking for a connection. Instead, switch the for loops order. make the connection first, then send your messages, then close the connection.

Comment: when you keep opening and closing the socket, you also drop the connection with your sender, so that may also be why you are noticing a "loss of packets".

Comment: @  bunbun your code break after 1st execution because of the data list is empty initially. but if i am doing  [data.append(datachunk)] this line before the [if not data] then it goes infinite time 
Please check your code again

Comment: Are you sure that's the error? data list SHOULD be empty at the start, and [data.append(datachunk)] is not valid code. I have changed .listen() to .listen(1). Try the new code now.

Comment: If the code is running infinitely, your receiver may not be connecting to the sender. You can check this by adding print statements before and after the `.accept` line. `accept` blocks (i.e. runs infinitely) until it connects to your sender.

Comment: @ bunbun but while loop break after one execution and gives [] list according to your new code

Comment: Oh, forgot to edit the `if not data` line when updating the code. It should be `if not datachunk`. Let me know how this goes.

Comment: @  bunbun yes i already did this but in this situtation, it runs only one time and then exit

Comment: You should really describe the errors you are getting to make it easier. Anyway, I have updated the receiver code and added a modified version of your sender code too. This works on your local machine, so you can modify the IPs to suit your own needs.

Comment: @  bunbun Now data is receiving at receiver end but not separately. It received in two messages (However 5 different message needed at receiver end)like below

Neighbor_list_sending;192.168.1.1;192.168.1.2

Neighbor_list_sending;192.168.1.2;192.168.1.3Neighbor_list_sending;192.168.1.2;192.168.1.4Neighbor_list_sending;192.168.1.4;192.168.1.5Neighbor_list_sending;192.168.1.4;192.168.1.6
But when I give some sleep time at sender side then it received correctly (5 messages received at receiver).

Comment: @usman1644 that is inevitable with plain TCP - it's a byte-streaming service.  Your sleep() bodge will not work reliably.  You need a message protocol on top of TCP for all application messages longer than one byte.

Comment: @  Martin James Can you tell me more detail, how i can develop message protocol or can you give some example using my above code?. 
Thanks for kind cooperation

Comment: @usman1644 Did you follow the code correctly? I received all 5 messages, added the output of my code in the solution above.

Comment: @bunbun I am getting different output. all messages are getting receive in two messages. Actually I am running a program through two raspberry pi, one as a sender and other as a receiver so i think that i why i am getting all messages in 2messages instead of 5 seperate like below 
['Neighbor_list_sending;192.168.1.1;192.168.1.2', 'Neighbor_list_sending;192.168.1.2;192.168.1.3''Neighbor_list_sending;192.168.1.2;192.168.1.4''Neighbor_list_sending;192.168.1.4;192.168.1.5' 'Neighbor_list_sending;192.168.1.4;192.168.1.6']
But when I give sleep time at sender side then I get 5 separate messages

Comment: @usman1644 are you getting two exact same messages or two parts? Ie. A, A or A1, A2? Or is it something else?

Comment: @bunbun two different messages A1,A2
One message contain 'Neighbor_list_sending;192.168.1.1;192.168.1.2' and second message contain 
'Neighbor_list_sending;192.168.1.2;192.168.1.3''Neighbor_list_sending;192.168.1.2;192.168.1.4''Neighbor_list_sending;192.168.1.4;192.168.1.5' 'Neighbor_list_sending;192.168.1.4;192.168.1.6

Comment: and both raspberries (Sender and receiver) are 1foot far away from each other. I mean distance between sender and receiver is 1-foot (30cm) maximum.

Comment: @ bunbun Can you help out how i can get acknowledgment message at sender side using TCP connection?
I want to use the acknowledgment message for getting confirmation of frame reception otherwise i want to resent that frame which is ack. not received..

Comment: So data = [A1, A2]? Just split up A2 with regex or split() https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/dictionary/python-split. For you acknowledgement thing, maybe post another question, its starting to get out of scope of this question.